# NullReferenceException while using Null Propagation

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, c#-6.0, null-propagation-operator

I am working on a **ASP.NET Core MVC** Application with **.NET Core 2.1.200**.

I have a response model and a static method to build this response model from the entity model.

```
public static EntityTypeResponseModel FromEntityType(Entity.EntityType entityType)
{
    return new EntityTypeResponseModel
    {
        Id = entityType.Id,
        Name = entityType.Name,

        // NullReferenceException
        Fields = entityType.EntityTypeFields?.Select(x => FieldResponseModel.FromField(x.Field))
    };
}
```

Although I use null propagation a NullReferenceException is thrown.

Doing a traditional null check fixes the issue:

```
public static EntityTypeResponseModel FromEntityType(Entity.EntityType entityType)
{
    var entityTypeResponseModel = new EntityTypeResponseModel
    {
        Id = entityType.Id,
        Name = entityType.Name
    };

    if (entityType.EntityTypeFields != null)
    {
        entityTypeResponseModel.Fields =
            entityType.EntityTypeFields?.Select(x => FieldResponseModel.FromField(x.Field));
    }

    return entityTypeResponseModel;
}
```

Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

Comment: What reference exactly is null when you debug?

Comment: The check for `EntityTypeFields` (collection) being not `null` doesn't check that `x` (element) isn't `null` as well. What is the type of `x.Field` and what does `.FromField` method do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a **mistake from myself**. The method `FieldResponseModel.FromField` expected a field which must not be null.

In the entity, I added entities (while going through the edit action of my controller) but via ID and not via entity object. After saving this object into the db context via `await _db.SaveChangesAsync()` the navigation property of the ID-property did not automatically set (which I was expecting).

I ended up getting the entity from the db myself and set the entity object.

```
// bad
junctionEntity.FieldId = 1

// good
junctionEntity.Field = await _db.Fields.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == 1)
```

This works **for me**, there may be other solutions out there.